# Best approach to perform AND OR NOT operations dynamically between Dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary, dynamic-programming

I am looking for an approach to solve below challenge:

- My code applies filters on Dataframes and return a Dataframe (any dataframe or think like Dataset)
- I can have n number of such dataframes and finally I need to do AND OR NOT between them.
- So finally I have n Dataframes and (n-1) operators between them AND with BRACKETS between them

What is the best approach to perform this operation in Python?
I am trying to keep the User Input to the simplest possible.

**Below is what I am thinking:**

1. user to provide plain string input like below:
2. ex1: `rs1 and rs2 and rs3 and rs4 and rs5`
3. ex2: `(rs1 and rs2) and rs3 and rs4 and rs5`

Somehow I will convert this string to an `OrderedDict`.
then I would have to traverse the `Dict` dynamically, from deepest level to the highest level recursively.

I would love to have suggestions on simpler approach or some pythonic pseudo-code on this approach please.

Answer (score 0):

Take input from User in the format you gave:

```
rs1 and rs2 and rs3 and rs4 and rs5
```

Use Regexp_replace and make it:

```
rs1 = 1 and rs2 = 1 and rs3 = 1 and rs4 = 1 and rs5= 1
```

in case of NOT, make it: `and rs5= 0`

Create a final string in Scala or Python and then pass that as:

```
Dataframe.filter("<filter str>")
```